# Инкремент указателя возвращает неверное значение

Tags: c, функции, указатели, инкремент

Столкнулся с одной странностью...

Есть функция с переменным числом аргументов:

```
void func(int32_t a, int32_t b, int32_t c){
    int32_t* ptr = &a;
    printf("%d\n", *(ptr++));
    printf("%d\n", *(ptr++));
    printf("%d\n", *(ptr++));
    printf("%d\n", *(ptr++));
    printf("%d\n", *(ptr++));
}
```

По какой-то причине выражение ptr++ не перемещает меня с &a к &b, а выдаёт 0, будто-бы int32_t = 2 байта???

Вот ожидаемый вывод:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Но по какой-то причине выводиться это:

```
1
0
2
0
3
```

Я полагаю дело в компиляторе?

Comment: Почему вы ожидаете такой вывод у  функции? Вообще, когда вы написали ptr++, то значение *ptr уже не опредлено(указывает на мусор).

Comment: Насколько я помню, аргументы функции идут в памяти подряд именно поэтому ptr++ хранящий &a будет указывать уже на &b, по крайней мере, так было у меня до смены компилятора.

Comment: Опять откуда-то это мнение, что работать с `...` надо через указатели... [`va_arg` и никак иначе](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments). Всё остальное — UB, и как именно добиваться переменного количества аргументов — дело компилятора!

Comment: Ничего подобного в стандарте не говорится, а компилятор мог запушить переменные на стек, и что вы вообще ждёте от такого кода не ясно.

Comment: Вы бы хоть ОС (обязательно 32 или 64-bit) и исполькуемый компайлер указали. К сведению, например  в 64-bit системах x-86 и ARM  (и многих 32-bit RISC) первые 8 аргументов передаются в регистрах (если вы в своем коде берете адрес такого аргумента, то только его копия появится в локальном стеке)

Comment: чтобы ваш код выполнялся, передавайте массив, как аргумент. `void func(int32_t ptr[]){}`. Вызов : `{int32_t arg[]={1,2,3,4,-1}; func(arg);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стандарте С не оговаривается как именно компилятор должен реализовывать размещение  аргументов функции на стеке.

В вашем случае результат говорит о том, что компилятор положил аргументы функции на стек с 64-битным выравниванием. Это нормально.